# Celery добавление переодичных задач пользователями

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, rabbitmq, celery

Как сделать интерфейс для пользователей, чтобы они сами добавляли переодичных задачи (или просто задачи), используя celery? 
Используется:
celery 4,
Rabbitmq,
Django.
Облазили всю документацию, а также кипу статей, негде о подобном не слова.

Answer (score 3):

Используйте задачи, точно так же, как обычные функции, а нужные переменные получайте во `views`, например:

Есть задача:

```
@shared_task
def sum(a,b)
    return a+b
```

Из интерфейса принимаете аргументы `a` и `b`, и во `view` вызываете эту функцию, например так:

```
def index(request):
    a = request.GET.get('a')
    b = requests.GET.get('b')
    task = sum.delay(a,b)
```

Если же задача для конкретного пользователя, то в задачу передаёте ещё и идентификатор пользователя, а внутри самой задачи проверяете, существует ли пользователь.

Например, нужно отправить письмо конкретному пользователю:

Сама задача:

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from celery import shared_task
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model


def send_mail_to_user(user_id):
    user = get_user_model().objects.get(pk=user_id)
    send_mail(
        'Subject here',
        'Here is the message.',
        'from@example.com',
        [user.email],
    fail_silently=False,
)
```

view:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def index(request):
    user_id = request.user.id
    tomorrow = datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(days=1)
    send_mail_to_user.apply_async((user_id), eta=tomorrow)
```

Таким образом ставится задача на отправку письма конкретному пользователю на завтра.

Если же вам нужно ставить периодические задачи, то у вас есть несколько вариантов, о них написано в разделе [periodic-tasks](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html)

Например, способ с использованием [celery-beat](https://django-celery-beat.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Задачи будут сохраняться в базе данных django, и планировщик может быть обновлен в модели задач на уровне db. Всякий раз, когда вы обновляете периодическую задачу, счетчик в этой таблице задач будет увеличиваться.

```
from django_celery_beat.models import PeriodicTask, IntervalSchedule

schedule= IntervalSchedule.objects.create(every=10, period=IntervalSchedule.SECONDS)
task = PeriodicTask.objects.create(interval=schedule, name='name of task', task='tasks.my_task', args=json.dumps([66]))
```

Это позволит не только давать возможность пользователям создавать задачи, но и полностью управлять планировщиком.

```
def update_task_view(request, id)
    task = PeriodicTask.objects.get(name="task name") 
    task.args=json.dumps([id])
    task.save()
```

[Здесь](https://django-celery-beat.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) описано подробнее, как работать с Celery beat

Я не проверял этот код, и не гарантирую, что он будет работать, но общая суть, я думаю, ясна.

Comment: Это понятно, а можно ли сделать ее переодичой? При помощи delay или же apply_sync?

Comment: Вам ведь придётся давать более тонкий контроль управления задачами. Для этого посмотрите на celery-beat

Comment: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html я хочу что-то подобное, только чтобы не хардкодить переодичные задачи, а можно было добавлять через пользовательский интерфейс.

Comment: @Тимур, как раз для этого и есть celery beat
https://django-celery-beat.readthedocs.io/en/latest/